# detached entity passed to persist

Tags: jpa, demoiselle

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema para persistir uma tela onde tenho um relacionamento de muitos para muitos, no caso grupoTrabalho_funcionario, tenho um tela que cadastro o grupo de trabalho e um picklist que cadastra os funcionários do grupoTrabalho.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem ao tentar salvar acontece o seguinte erro:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain.Funcionario
```

O que fazer para resolver esse erro?

Minha classe GrupoTrabalho:

```
    package br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Audited
@Entity
@Table(schema = "DBO")
public class GrupoTrabalho implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_grupoTrabalho")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tx_nomeGrupo", nullable = false)
    private String nomeGrupo;

    @Column(name = "isAtivo")
    private boolean ativo;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataCadastro = new Date();

    //cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "grupoTrabalho_funcionarios", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "grupoTrabalho_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "funcionario_id"))
    private List<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<Funcionario>(); 


    public GrupoTrabalho() {

    }

    public GrupoTrabalho(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public GrupoTrabalho(String nomeGrupo, boolean ativo, Date dataCadastro) {
        super();
        this.nomeGrupo = nomeGrupo;
        this.ativo = ativo;
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
    }

    public GrupoTrabalho(String nomeGrupo, boolean ativo,
            Date dataCadastro, List<Funcionario> funcionarios) {
        super();
        this.nomeGrupo = nomeGrupo;
        this.ativo = ativo;
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
        this.funcionarios = funcionarios;
    }

    //getters and setters..




}
```

Minha classe Funcionário:

```
    package br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.validation.annotation.Cpf;


@Audited    
@Entity
@Table(schema = "DBO")
public class Funcionario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_Funcionario")
    private Long id;

    @Cpf
    @Column(name = "tx_CPF")
    private String cpf;
    @Column(name = "tx_Nome")
    private String nome;
    @Min(value = 1,message = "Não pode ser zero")
    @Column(name = "nu_Matricula")
    private int matricula;
    @Email
    @Column(name = "tx_Email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "tx_Telefone",length = 15)
    private String telefone;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="funcionarios")
    private List<GrupoTrabalho> gruposTrabalhos;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_SitFuncionario_fk", nullable=false)
    private SitFuncionario sitFuncionario;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cargo_FK",nullable=false)
    private Cargo cargo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_Lotacao_FK",nullable=false)
    private Lotacao lotacao;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_FuncaoFuncionario_fk")
    private FuncaoFuncionario funcaoFuncionario;


    public Funcionario(){

    }

    public Funcionario(String cpf){
        this.cpf = cpf;

    }

    public Funcionario(Long id){
        this.id = id;

    }


    public Funcionario(String cpf, String nome, int matricula, String email,
            String telefone, SitFuncionario sitFuncionario, Cargo cargo,
            Lotacao lotacao, FuncaoFuncionario funcaoFuncionario, List<GrupoTrabalho> gruposTrabalhos) {
        super();
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.sitFuncionario = sitFuncionario;
        this.cargo = cargo;
        this.lotacao = lotacao;
        this.funcaoFuncionario = funcaoFuncionario;
        this.gruposTrabalhos = gruposTrabalhos;
    }

    public Funcionario(String cpf, String nome, int matricula, String email,
            String telefone) {
        super();
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    getters and setters
```

Meu ManageBean GrupoTrabalhoMB:

```
package br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.primefaces.event.TransferEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.annotation.PreviousView;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.ViewController;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.template.AbstractEditPageBean;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.Transactional;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.business.FuncionarioBC;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.business.GrupoTrabalhoBC;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain.Funcionario;
import br.gov.ro.portovelho.semfaz.sisfiscal.domain.GrupoTrabalho;

// To remove unused imports press: Ctrl+Shift+o

@ViewController
@PreviousView("./grupoTrabalho_list.jsf")
public class GrupoTrabalhoEditMB extends AbstractEditPageBean<GrupoTrabalho, Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private GrupoTrabalhoBC grupoTrabalhoBC;

    private DualListModel<Funcionario> funcionarioList;

    @Inject
    private FuncionarioBC funcionarioBC;

    public void setFuncionarioList(DualListModel<Funcionario> funcionarioList) {
        this.funcionarioList = funcionarioList;
    }

    public void addFuncionarioList(List<Funcionario> funcionarioList) {
        this.getBean().getFuncionarios().addAll(funcionarioList);
    }

    public void deleteFuncionarioList(List<Funcionario> funcionarioList) {
        this.getBean().getFuncionarios().removeAll(funcionarioList);
    }


    public DualListModel<Funcionario> getFuncionarioList() {
        if (this.funcionarioList == null) {
            List<Funcionario> source = funcionarioBC.findAll();
            List<Funcionario> target = this.getBean().getFuncionarios();

            if (source == null) {
                source = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
            }
            if (target == null) {
                target = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
            }else{
                source.removeAll(target);
            }
            this.funcionarioList = new DualListModel<Funcionario>(source, target);

        }
        return this.funcionarioList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
        if (event.isAdd()){
            this.addFuncionarioList((List<Funcionario>) event.getItems());
        }
        if (event.isRemove()) {
            this.deleteFuncionarioList((List<Funcionario>) event.getItems());
         }
    } 

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String delete() {

        this.grupoTrabalhoBC.delete(getId());
        return getPreviousView();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String insert() {
        //TODO Náo está inserindo automaticamente a lista de muitos para muitos entre grupo e vários funcionários do grupo
        //this.getBean().setFuncionarios(null);
        this.grupoTrabalhoBC.insert(this.getBean());
        return getPreviousView();
    }

    @Override
    public String update() {
        //this.getBean().setFuncionarios(null);
        this.grupoTrabalhoBC.update(this.getBean());
        return getPreviousView();
    }

    @Override
    protected GrupoTrabalho handleLoad(Long id) {
        return this.grupoTrabalhoBC.load(id);
    }   
}
```

Comment: conseguiu resolver? a resposta abaixo ajudou?

Comment: Resolvido: Para resolver tive que fazer da seguinte forma, na classe Funcionário anotei com @LazyCollection e troquei arrayList para Set: `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="funcionarios",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<GrupoTrabalho> gruposTrabalhos;`

Comment: Cuidado com o FetchType.EAGER, pois ele vai carregar todos os objetos `gruposTrabalhos` junto com o retrieve do Funcionário, aumentando assim o consumo de memória.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este erro acontece quando você tenta persistir um objeto com o ID já preenchido, sendo que o ID é auto incrementável.

Você pode sempre antes de persistir setar para null o id, ou tentar realizar o merge, ou utilizar o método:

```
saveOrUpdate()
```